# Backing up PS4 game data to external USB drive - missing a critical step?

Tags: ps4, ps5

A few months ago I followed a guide in the official Sony page [Back up and restore PS4 data with external storage device](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/support/hardware/ps4-back-up-and-restore-with-external-storage/). It claims this will backup all adult and child accounts. It all seemed to work fine.

Yesterday we finally got our PS5, and I was able to use the external drive to restore my PS4 game data to my account. Then my daughter logged in with her account (I logged out of mine), but when we attempted to import her game data, there is nothing shown (as if the external drive is empty).

I've searched online everywhere for a solution to this, but nobody else seems to have this problem.

My thinking is, perhaps the original Sony page I mentioned above (and absolutely every YouTube video on the same subject) is missing an important step: Did I have to export the game data to the USB drive while logged into each account separately on the PS4? So for example, be logged into my, export my game data. Then log into my daughters account, export her game data. Then log into my wife's account, export her game data.

Because if that's the case, then absolutely nobody - even Sony - is mentioning this.

As it stands right now I am the only one in the family who has been able to successfully transfer PS4 data to the PS5, and I'm feeling like the worst Dad in the world.

FYI we do not have the original PS4 any more (we sold it a few months ago) and no cloud account.

For what it's worth, here's a screenshot (below) of what the backup data looks like. The SAVEDATA directory only has one folder, called 79da45a87cf4451.

Anyway, I'm trying to get confirmation on this. I followed the instruction to the letter, and only my game data was able to be restored to the PS5. If I've messed up, I'd like to know how. But if I did everything right, why can't I restore the game data for the rest of my family?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've recently replaced the drive in my PS4, and this was one of the procedures I had looked up on the Sony site.

Mine's an online account(the other 3 are not), and I had the same experience you had, including the child accounts backup missing info.

I ended up having to stick the old drive back in and do an export from each account, logged in as that account to have everything carry over.